# CSS display:block problem, whos the culprit IE or Firefox?

Tags: css

I am having a hard time figuring out why things look so different in IE and Firefox.
Here is a CSS class

```
.logo { width: 224px; height: 120px; position: relative;
    display:block; left: -1px; background-image: url(logo.png);}
```

In IE this works as expected, but in Firefox it behaves like a drunk! I see 3 logo.png at different places on a page. If I remove display:block then I cannot see the image in either browser.

Any comments appreciated.

Comment: You might need to post some HTML.

Comment: Thanks so much for all replies. Here is a link for a sample page which is driving me nuts 

http://india3.fasttrackteam.com:8080/sample/sample.htm . 

The funny thing is the mark up does not have multiple images, but Firebug inspects them as multiple images!

Answer (score 6):

You might need to add

```
background-repeat: none;
```

to your css class. And for future reference, it's always IE that screws up ;)

**EDIT:** If that doesn't solve your problem, please put up a sample site live somewhere we can look at it and experiment a little. Also, [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) might be helpful.

**EDIT2:** Removed this, since I noted the difference between firebug and the src I got from right-clicking and selecting "View Source..."

**EDIT3:** Steve found your problem: You can't self-close anchors. Change

```
<a href="/" id="logo" />
```

to

```
<a href="/" id="logo"></a>
```

Comment: "it's always IE that screws up ;)" <== True... true... ;)

Comment: he doesn't have three #logo ids, just a self closed A tag. Thus FF is attempting to fix his HTML

Comment: Thanks a ton guys. That was it. 
Moral of the story.
IE is still the culprit :)).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the HTML.  You can't can't self close A tags

Answer (score 1):

Correct, the problem is always IE. If firefox has an issue it's usually an issue with the w3c specs. Not being a fanboy, it's just the way things are.

I guessing your problem is that the default value for background-repeat is different between the browsers. You should try setting background-repeat:no-repeat EDIT: Maybe not, all browsers default to repeat.

It would be useful to know what element you are applying logo to. Whatever it is is probably collapsing to a height of 0px when not a block. Put a border on it to see what's going on there.